# Pandas module not found after pip install inside virtual env and pip show pandas finds package

Tags: python, pandas

Getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` inside my virtual env created with Python 3.8.9

Installed `pandas` with pip version 21.3.1

`>>> pip show pandas`

```
Name: pandas
Version: 1.3.4
Summary: Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
Home-page: https://pandas.pydata.org
Author: The Pandas Development Team
Author-email: pandas-dev@python.org
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /Users/homeyy/Documents/projects/scripts/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: numpy, python-dateutil, pytz
Required-by:
```

pip is able to find the pandas package but python is not???

Comment: Typically this is caused by a virtualenv not being activated. If you run the command `which python` and the command `which pip`, what path does it show you? A path to your virtualenv, or somewhere else?

Comment: you're right, `python` was linking to outside the virtual env even tho I was inside the virtual env, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you haven't activated the venv, because when `pip` understands a package but `python` doesn't, it's because `pip` isn't serving Python installation that `python` is pointing to. You can check what Python installation `pip` is serving by running `pip --version`.

Try activating your venv like this: `source <path/to/venv>/bin/activate`.